# JSON.parse fails for negative floating point numbers

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, floating-point, string-parsing

I have a simple script like this:

```
request = $.ajax({
          url: "/getmesomefloats.php",
          type: "post",
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // Log a message to the console
            console.log(response, textStatus);
            if(textStatus == 'success') {
              console.log($.parseJSON(response);
            }
        });
```

Where getmesomefloats.php looks like this:

```
  $points[] = array(-14.27664,-170.6878);
  $points[] = array(-16.29323,-165.3741);
  $points[] = array(-15.86157,-162.7885);
  $points[] = array(-15.89847,-160.2066);
  echo json_encode($all_points);
```

the first console log call spits out this string:

```
[[-14.27664,-170.6878],[-16.29323,-165.3741],[-15.86157,-162.7885],[-15.89847,-160.2066]] success
```

The $.parseJSON (or JSON.parse(response)) spits out this ("expanded" in the console):

```
[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]
  0: Array[2]
    0: -1589268.2950388812
    1: NaN
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
  1: Array[2]
    0: -1813754.066977689
    1: NaN
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
  2: Array[2]
    0: -1765701.8955818643
    1: NaN
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
  3: Array[2]
    0: -1769809.5847921362
    1: NaN
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
  length: 4
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

I don't understand why I get the NaN's and why eg -14.27664 is converted to -1589268.2950388812 ? What should I do to get the correct values?
Are the floating point numbers to much to handle for javascript?
Bonus info: The floats are GPS coordinates, and I ('m going to) use them in a map script not included here.

Comment: Why not put them in a string i am not sure what's is causing this.
Because i just strings for floating points

Comment: There is no reason why there would be any problem to handle floating point values, JavaScript uses double precision floating point numbers for all numbers. When I try to parse that string using JSON.parse in Firefox, it works just fine. What brower are you using?

Comment: Hi Guffa and Bob, I'm using Chrome. Bob, If I were to use the string would you suggest that I write some custom function to parse the returned array? Could the error be browser related?

Comment: Hi All, I am facing the similar issue with negative floating point value in JSON

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with parsing negative values from some data I copy/pasted from wikipedia.  It turned out that the minus sign was the wrong character (ascii decimal 150 instead of 45).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in `[[-14.27664,-170.6878],[-16.29323,-165.3741],[-15.86157,-162.7885],[-15.89847,-160.2066]]` given that JavaScript can't handle.

[image: Output]

Maybe you could try including the raw output from your request in case there is something I can't see in the console.log output you gave.

Comment: Thank you for your help - how do I post the raw output?